# Wait for user input from readline module (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, readline

I am creating a module to get experience and shorten some code. I have a piece of code which uses readline in a simplified manner, like `var x = arkin.question("How old are you? ");`. Readline doesn't wait for the answer. It produces this:

> How old are you? undefined

Code:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

exports.question = function(q){

  var response;

  rl.setPrompt(q);
  rl.prompt();
  rl.on('line', (userInput) => {
    response = userInput;
    rl.close();
  });

  rl.on('close', () => {
    return response;
  });
}
```

I call it like this:

```
var age = arkin.question("How old are you? ");
console.log(age);
```

I have tried using this code:

```
rl.question(q, (userInput) => {
    rl.close;
    response = userInput;
    return response;
});
```

Yet I get the same result. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

whenever you call `arki.question` it registeres the event listeners .on("line") and .on("close") then returns from the function. Whatever you returning from .on("close") event listener `question` function does not know about it, because it is no longer on the call stack. you can either use a callback or promises with `async...await` to get your result.

### with callbacks

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

exports.question = function(q , cb ){

    var response;

    rl.setPrompt(q);
    rl.prompt();

    rl.on('line', (userInput) => {
        response = userInput;
        rl.close();
    });

    rl.on('close', () => {
        return cb(response);
    });
};
```

you call it like this

```
var age  = arki.question("how old are you? ", resp => {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

### with promises

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

exports.question = function(q){

    var response;

    rl.setPrompt(q);
    rl.prompt();

    return new Promise(( resolve , reject) => {

        rl.on('line', (userInput) => {
            response = userInput;
            rl.close();
        });

        rl.on('close', () => {
            resolve(response);
        });

    });


};
```

you call it like this

```
arki.question("how old are you? ").then( response => console.log(response) );
```

or

```
; ( async () => {
    console.log(await arki.question("how old are you? "));
})();
```

Comment: Ok, now i understand, but doing this is just as complex as using it normally. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should put const r1 = readline.createInterface(...) within the question function otherwise it only works the first time.

Comment: Your promise-based version was super helpful to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//global stuff, where we import readline. 
//But avoid assigning global vars.
    var age;
    var readline = require('readline'), menu;
        
//define function
    function whatever() = {
    
//create readline instance and assign it to menu
    menu = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
        
//Use the readline.question method, which is what you're looking for.
//It requires a callback function with a variable for the users input.
    menu.question('How old are you? ', function(input) {
        age = input;
    });
        
    console.log(`You are ${age} years old.`);
}
        
//Tell node to run the program
whatever();
```

Comment: Please explain your code.